# How can my commonLib.dll use the referencing applications app.config?

Tags: c#

Ok so i have 2 classes so far that i want to put in my common dll, logger and db. im moving them from my current project to a new class library project and changing their namespaces and whatnot. The issue I am having is that I wish to use the app config of my application (or any app that I want to reference my commonlib.dll) but I dont know how to use the referencing projects app.config. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenExeConfiguration() methods of ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager_methods.aspx) are your ticket. One of them will take a path to the executable, allowing you to open the app config of a specified application (even a different one; you can use this technique to change the configuration of another application before launching it with Process.Start()). The other one will open the app.config of the current application (even if your library is used by multiple apps) for a specified user level (All users, current roaming user, and current roaming and local user). Usually, when dealing with an actual app.config, you want the one that applies to all users; the per-user configs are stored in each user's AppData folders.

Also, one last thing; unless your library has its own config file, the ConfigurationManager properties, like AppSettings, will be populated based on the current executable's app.config. So it could be as simple as using those properties. Keep in mind that those properties are read-only and only loaded once at program startup, so if you make changes to your config during program execution that you want to be effective immediately, it's better to explicitly load/save config files.

Comment: ah ok, so something like OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location)

Comment: or GetEntryAssembly() which is the assembly invoked by the shell or unmanaged code to start up the CLR. Like I said, you'd only have to specify the executable if your own library has its own app.config; otherwise, OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None) should be fine.